# Get Quicktime Video Info

Tags: macos, video, ffmpeg, quicktime

Is there a way to get QuickTime video information? (In googling it, I found one cl option for QT that was broken.)

I am looking to find pasp, length, audio channels, audio assignment, clap, and an assortment of other properties that is often found using the program "Dumpster". Most of this information is unavailable using ffmpeg.

Comment: You could make a feature request on the [FFmpeg bug tracker](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki). Some features are implemented quickly, but it mostly depends on developer interest.

Comment: David542, what did you end up settling on, I am looking for the same thing. Mediainfo seems to give the most info. Pasp and clap (clean aperture) seem to be the hardest things to determine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using an QuickTime sample from [Apple site](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1425) I can even get the ouput in a nicely JSON format:

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format sample_iTunes.mov 
{
    "format": {
        "filename": "sample_iTunes.mov",
        "nb_streams": 2,
        "format_name": "mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2",
        "format_long_name": "QuickTime / MOV",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "85.500000",
        "size": "3284257",
        "bit_rate": "307298",
        "tags": {
            "major_brand": "qt  ",
            "minor_version": "537199360",
            "compatible_brands": "qt  ",
            "creation_time": "2005-10-17 22:54:32"
        }
    }
}
```

I've used ffprobe version 1.0.7

Answer (score 2):

Mediainfo is a nice utility, http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en .It will give some of the info you need. Also look at ffprobe, It takes options like -show_streams and -show_frames to get more details.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option: http://omino.com/sw/qt_tools/

Though the program itself is broken, if you run $ `pieces/bin/qt_info <.mov file>` it will give you some nice information.